# how to add nebula dependency to maven project?

Tags: java, maven, nebula

I am trying to add a dependency to nebula to a small project, because I want to use nebula gridviewer and ganttchart.

I use maven to build my project.

What should I put in my `pom.xml` file? I am not able to find any hint online...

Comment: if you cannot find sth, you can also use the jar you want and install it to your local repository with artifact and group id you want and reference to that.

Comment: yes, but I am not even able to find the pre-compiled jars....

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to 
[nebula release download page](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/downloads.php)

and download the repository.zip.

Inside the zip you can find all the jars for nebula project. you can install to your local maven repository the ones you want to use to your project.

Comment: both those jar are not the compiled ones, they are just sources and examples. Is there a particular maven plugin to compile them?

Comment: did you download the correct one? it has compiled java classes too! check org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid_1.0.0.201310152148.jar file.

Comment: Is it possible to reference some nebula repo within pom.xml? And the dependency to any widget will be automatically resolved?

Comment: no idea my friend. you have to check if the dependencies are hosted at the repo you want to include and decide what to do

Comment: @Apostolos +1, this is also the way I do it. I download the repository and deploy only the jars I need to Artifactory. Unfortunately I found that I have to remove META-INF/maven folder from the jars before deploying to artifactory (and then manually typing the groupId, artifactId, version), otherwise Maven complains about missing parent poms that aren't actually required.

Comment: @tomalone you may be able to use their update site at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/nebula/snapshot/ however I cannot recommend this. Nebula regularly publishes new snapshot versions. You should not rely on snapshot resolution: Maven will regularly download the newer version which means your build is not repeatable. Besides the possibility that someone introduces a new bug, the behavior of your program may differ in subtle ways even when your own code hasn't changed.

Comment: Answer is not answering the question about getting the jar from Maven

Comment: if jars arent included in maven central repository you have to find another way of using them, even if this means installing them to your local repo. this also happens with other jars like sql server jdbc jars or db2 jdbc jars. since they are not available publicly via the central or an alternate repo how can you use them without installing them in your local repo? this is the ONLY solution for such jars.