# How to add maven dependency for Nebula Pagination Control and how to use this widget on Composite?

Tags: java, maven, swt, nebula

I have lot of groups which is rendered on scroll composite and now I want to implement Pagination so that I control data flow on my scroll composite. And how I add Pagination dependency in my pom.xml.

Comment: This looks like two completely separate questions. You should ask one question at a time as someone who can answer an SWT question may not be able to answer a Maven question.

Comment: yes you right but I can't find anywhere how to add to my pom.xml means what should I write in my pom to achieve this.

Comment: No idea about the SWT part but as for the dependencies see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19451248/1570834